# Automatically convert files to h265 in a certain folder

Tags: video, ffmpeg, freenas, transcode

**What I am currently doing**

Everything is running on freenas (linux). I always have to go into the shell and start a script to transcode everything inside the folder.
To be exact: I go to the shell and change to the directory then i type in `tcsh -c ./HEVC_28CRF`

"HEVC_28CRF" is the name of the script.
It contains: `for i in *.mkv; do ffmpeg -i "$i" -c:v libx265 -crf 28 -c:a copy -map 0 -c:s copy "${i%.*}HEVC.mkv"; done`

**I have 2 issues:**

**#1** I want to have a folder that always checks automatically if there are new files. If there are new files they should be transcoded using the script that i have in the same folder.

**#2** As you can see, my script will change the name of the input file and add "HEVC" at the end. So if the input file is named "Test" the output file will be named "TestHEVC". I want the output file to have the same name as the input file. I dont need the input file after the transcoding is finished. Is there an option to kind of replace the original file while transcoding? So I konw I have to change my script, but i don't know what i should change.

So I need a change in “HEVC_28CRF”, which solves the 2 issues.

Thanks in advance, I appreciate any help!

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Sorry, i am new. What did I do wrong?

Comment: "So i need a new script, and a method to run it automatically"

Comment: So, is this clear enough?

Comment: @DonShiro - what people are saying is, learn some basic scripting.

Comment: @DonShiro - take a look at that script, and _try to think how you might change it_.

Comment: I don’t know, that’s why I am here. I have some basic Java knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

1. scheduler?
2. exclude "*HEVC.mkv", remove input file after encoding.

   ```
    for f in *.mkv; do
      [[ $f =~ HEVC.mkv$ ]] && continue
      ffmpeg -i "$f" -map 0 -c:v libx265 -crf 28 -c:a copy -c:s copy "${f%.*}HEVC.mkv"
      rm $f
    done
   ```

something like this.